# Python Protobuf (IPv4/IPv6 address) into Clickhouse FixedString(16)

Tags: python-3.x, protocol-buffers, clickhouse

Using a simple protobuf definition like so:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package flowprotobuf;

message FlowMessage {
    bytes SourceIP = 6;
    bytes DestIP = 7;
}
```

What is the proper way to encode an IPv4/IPv6 address so as to insert it into a Clickhouse table with `FixedString(16)` types set for both `SourceIP` and `DestIP`?

After days of riding the struggle bus I'm currently doing the following (Python 3) to dump the protobuf stream to a Kafka topic (and then consuming via Clickhouse Kafka engine & materialized view) with a "good" result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import flow_pb2
from google.protobuf.internal.encoder import _VarintBytes
from socket import inet_pton, AF_INET, AF_INET6
from binascii import hexlify

def pack_addr(ipaddr):
    if ':' in ipaddr:
        l = int(hexlify(inet_pton(AF_INET6, ipaddr)), 16)
        return l.to_bytes(16, byteorder='big')
    else:
        l = int(hexlify(inet_pton(AF_INET, ipaddr)), 16)
        return l.to_bytes(16, byteorder='big')

fm = flow_pb2.FlowMessage()
fm.SourceIP = pack_addr(ip_src)
fm.DestIP = pack_addr(ip_dst)

size = fm.ByteSize()
fpb = _VarintBytes(size) + fm.SerializeToString()

producer.produce(kafka_producer_topic, fpb)
producer.poll(0)
```

I put good in quotes because according to the [Clickhouse documentation](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/ip-address-functions/#ipv6numtostringx) for `IPv6NumToString()`:

> Accepts a FixedString(16) value containing the IPv6 address in binary format. Returns a string containing this address in text format.
> IPv6-mapped IPv4 addresses are output in the format ::ffff:111.222.33.44.

However my query results are not showing the `::ffff:x.x.x.x` format - instead:

```
de33137dfc80 :) SELECT Date,TimeReceived,IPv6NumToString(SourceIP),IPv6NumToString(DestIP) FROM test LIMIT 5;

SELECT
    Date,
    TimeReceived,
    IPv6NumToString(SourceIP),
    IPv6NumToString(DestIP)
FROM test
LIMIT 5

┌───────Date─┬────────TimeReceived─┬─IPv6NumToString(SourceIP)─┬─IPv6NumToString(DestIP)─┐
│ 2020-08-05 │ 2020-08-05 06:41:27 │ ::98.158.157.211          │ ::202.122.147.98        │
│ 2020-08-05 │ 2020-08-05 06:41:27 │ ::98.158.157.211          │ ::217.118.23.125        │
│ 2020-08-05 │ 2020-08-05 06:41:27 │ ::192.34.21.69            │ ::104.34.73.41          │
│ 2020-08-05 │ 2020-08-05 06:41:27 │ ::98.158.157.211          │ ::194.28.167.103        │
│ 2020-08-05 │ 2020-08-05 06:41:27 │ ::98.158.148.89           │ ::79.170.71.49          │
└────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┘

5 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.006 sec.
```

I know the IPv4 addresses are correct, and it's also properly showing IPv6 addresses. I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything glaring/obvious. Thanks.

Edited to add: Clickhouse server version 20.5.4 revision 54435

EDIT 2: Denis's suggestion below led me to come up with the solution:

```
    else:
        m = '::ffff:' + ipaddr
        l = int(hexlify(inet_pton(AF_INET6, m)), 16)
        return l.to_bytes(16, byteorder='big')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT hex(IPv6StringToNum('::98.158.157.211'))

┌─hex(IPv6StringToNum('::98.158.157.211'))─┐
│ 000000000000000000000000629E9DD3         │
└──────────────────────────────────────────┘

SELECT hex(IPv6StringToNum('::ffff:98.158.157.211'))

┌─hex(IPv6StringToNum('::ffff:98.158.157.211'))─┐
│ 00000000000000000000FFFF629E9DD3              │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

*https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address
For example, the IPv4-mapped IPv6 address ::ffff:c000:0280 is written as ::ffff:192.0.2.128, thus expressing clearly the original IPv4 address that was mapped to IPv6*

https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipv4toipv6
0:0:0:0:0:ffff:629e:9dd3

[Converting IPv4 Address to a Hex IPv6 Address in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750929/converting-ipv4-address-to-a-hex-ipv6-address-in-python)

Comment: Cheers Denis! I'll use the `ipaddress` module to convert all v4 IP's to the mapped types. Thanks.